# Question about ODE of the first order

Tags: real-analysis

We consider $a:(-3,3) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $b:(-1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and the following Cauchy problem:
$$ \begin{cases}  y'=a(x)b(y) \\ y(x_0)=y_0 \end{cases} $$
with $x_0 \in (-3,3)$. If $a$ and $ b$ are continuous functions, may this problem  have no solutions?

Comment: Yes.  Easy to make $y$ falls outside $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Comment: Example: $a(x)=10$ for all $x\in(-3,3)$, $b(y)=10$ for all $y\in(-1,1)$, so the DE is $y'=100$ and $y(x)\in(-1,1)$ for all $x\in(-3,3)$, which is impossible regardless of your starting $x_0,y_0$.  Or just make $y_0\notin(-1,1)$.

Comment: Ok it is clear thank you. I have another question, if a solution there exists, under the assumption that the two functions are continuous, this funcion is of class $C^1$, it is right?